# PostgreSQL Error: column am.amcanorder doesn't exist

Tags: postgresql, ant

I am working on CentOS release 6.8 (Final) based server without sudo access. I compiled PostgreSQL v9.6 beta 2.

When I am loading data using ant, I get *am.amcanorder column doesn't exist* error which I don't know how to fix.

I am following a tutorial to set up Intermine data warehousing system and I am on [this step](http://intermine.readthedocs.io/en/latest/get-started/tutorial/#loading-data-from-a-source).

---

```
 ant -Dsource=uniprot-malaria -v
```

This will take a couple of minutes to complete, the command runs the
   following steps:

- Checks that a source with name uniprot-malaria exists in project.xml
- Reads the UniProt XML files at the location specified by src.data.dir
- Calls the parser included in the uniprot source with the list of
  files, this reads the original XML and creates Items which are
  metadata representations of the objects that will be loaded into the
  malariamine database.
- These items are stored in an intermediate items database. Reads from
  the items database, **converts items to objects and loads them into the
  malariamine database**.

---

The bold part is what (in my opinion) causing the error. The relevant error verbose is:

```
org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: column am.amcanorder does not exist
  Position: 407
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.receiveErrorResponse(QueryExecutorImpl.java:2161)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.processResults(QueryExecutorImpl.java:1890)
        at org.postgresql.core.v3.QueryExecutorImpl.execute(QueryExecutorImpl.java:255)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.execute(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:559)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeWithFlags(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:403)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2Statement.executeQuery(AbstractJdbc2Statement.java:283)
        at org.postgresql.jdbc2.AbstractJdbc2DatabaseMetaData.getIndexInfo(AbstractJdbc2DatabaseMetaData.java:4234)
        at org.intermine.task.CreateIndexesTask.execute(CreateIndexesTask.java:212)
        at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
```

Comment: @ErwinBrandstetter updated, although I think the problem is with postgresql itself and not the code I'm running...

Comment: It's a Postgres error message for sure. The column `amcanorder` is not found in table `am`. I have no insight why, though.

Comment: Yeah I couldn't find any real info, at least not what I understand. Will answer my own question if I somehow get past this error.

Comment: Can you check to see that the `am` table exists? If not, is there another table that has the amcanorder column in it? It's possible that the table name has been updated but the initialization code/script has not.

Comment: An update to the JDBC driver was merged as a pull request into intermine (which is the software that OP is talking about) so the issue should be fixed upstream https://github.com/intermine/intermine/pull/1475

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Well the problem was fixed by compiling v9.5.3, the latest stable version at this time. Previously, I was using v9.6beta2 ... which has a [reported error](https://www.postgresql.org/message-id/CAB%3DJe-FUuFi0jUi4BCiTi5WuguJLgek%3Dk2nt6LkZ8GfghVQbwQ%40mail.gmail.com) when working with JDBC & v9.6beta2.

Comment: The much higher, newer (non-accepted) answer is the better solution. This answer is superseeded by it.

Answer (score 48):

Player87 is right, it works just by replacing the newer version 9.6* with 9.5.* of the *PostgresSQL* **server**.
But, there is another solution. For a Java project, I have also tried leaving *PostgresSQL* **server** on 9.6.* and updated the PostgresSQL driver, from version 9.4-1203 to the newest one 9.4-1211.
In a maven pom.xml file:

```
<postgresql.version>9.4.1211</postgresql.version>
```

That worked for me too.

Comment: Thank you. Worked beautifully. I don't like non-critical errors reported in my logs. Makes me uneasy.

Comment: Moving to latest driver version solved the problem for java.

Comment: Upgrade from 9.4.1208 to 9.4.1211 worked for mee too.

Comment: works for me when upgrading from 9.4.1208 to 9.4.1212 for Hive 2.3.8

Answer (score 12):

For me (connecting to PostgreSQL from a Java/Maven application and facing the same error) it was a driver issue.

Updating PostgreSQL driver from 9.4-1201-jdbc41 to 42.1.4 resolved it.
My Maven dependency now looks like this:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
        <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        <version>42.1.4</version>
    </dependency>
```

Comment: Yes. I faced the same problem, above version 42.1.4 works fine

Comment: For 9.6, can use version 42.2.6.

Answer (score 7):

I faced the same issue with SpringBoot and have solved this by upgrading my driver

For Spring Boot 1.4.0 I just added the following Dependency

`<dependency>
      <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
      <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
  </dependency>`

Comment: This is true, but only if your project is a submodule of spring boot, as it inherits dependencies from Spring Boot. Besides, not specifying the version  lead to the usage of the latest version.

Answer (score 0):

In My case, I was using a PostgreSQL driver(9.4.1204) and not compatible with hive external metastore. Worked after replacing with the latest version from https://jdbc.postgresql.org/download.html.